# Extract elasticsearch data with talend

Tags: elasticsearch, talend

[image]In this project, i want to extract the message from elasticsearch data with talend, so i have installed the elasticsearch components pack 'tElasticSearch-Components' from the TalendExchange Components
https://github.com/jlolling/talendcomp_tElasticSearch
The problem is that le log in the file is in desired format, but when I execute the GET API, the message have specials caracters so i can't read it.
In the same time, I want to extract the message with tExtractJsonField component, and after that I'll transform the message as i want.[image]

---

I recieve this error while executing my job , " Un caractère XML non valide (Unicode : 0x19) a été détecté dans le contenu d'élément du document. Nested exception: Un caractère XML non valide (Unicode : 0x19) a été détecté dans le contenu d'élément du document."
[image]